# Why would DDPG with Hindsight Experience Replay not converge?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, rewards, ddpg, hindsight-experience-replay

I am trying to train a DDPG agent augmented with Hindsight Experience Replay (HER) to solve [the KukaGymEnv environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT1Rh.png).  The actor and critic are simple neural networks with two hidden layers (as in the HER paper).

More precisely, the hyper-parameters I am using are

- The actor's hidden layer's sizes: [256, 128] (using ReLU activations and a tanh activation after the last layer)
- Critic's hidden layer's sizes: [256, 128] (Using ReLU activations)
- Maximum Replay buffer size: 50000
- Actor learning rate: 0.000005 (Adam Optimizer)
- Critic learning rate: 0.00005 (Adam Optimizer)
- Discount rate: 0.99
- Polyak constant : 0.001
- The transitions are sampled in batches of 32 from the replay buffer for training
- Update rate: 1 (target networks are updated after each time step)
- The action selection is stochastic with the noise being sampled from a normal distribution of mean 0 and standard deviation of 0.7

I trained the agent for 25 episodes with a maximum of 700 time-steps each and got the following reward plot:

[image]

The reward shoots up to a very high value of about 8000 for the second episode and steeply falls to -2000 in the very next time step, never to rise again. What could be the reason for this behavior and how can I get it to converge?

PS : One difference I observed while training this agent from while training a simple DDPG agent is that for simple DDPG, the episode would usually terminate at around 450 time-steps, thus never reaching the maximum specified timesteps. However, here, no episode terminated before the specified 700 maximum time steps. This might have something to do with the performance.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?